# serviceWorker on LAMP doesn't exist

Tags: apache2, port, service-worker, lamp

I'm testing serviceWorker according "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers"

My PC with Ubuntu 18.04, apache2 v2.4.29, Firefox 69.0.1

I saw that serviceWorker functions only on HTTPS domains but also, for testing, on port 80 and localhost.

I test it on one of my test domains, outilsrouteur.test, where /etc/apache2/sites-available/outilsrouteur.test.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName outilsrouteur.test
        ServerAlias www.outilsrouteur.test
        DocumentRoot ***/siteoutilsrouteur  // *** = my real directory
        <Directory ***/siteoutilsrouteur> // *** = my real directory
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
            Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            AllowOverride all
            Require local
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog ***/siteoutilsrouteur/error.log.txt
    CustomLog /access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and etc/apache2/port.conf is:

```
Listen 80
```

I have barely modified app.js as:

```
console.log("===================\napp.js :\n\n"); //****
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
console.log("serviceWorker existe");
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw-test/sw.js', {scope: './sw-test/'})
  .then((reg) => {
    // registration worked
    console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
  }).catch((error) => {
    // registration failed
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
} else {  //****
console.log("serviceWorker n'existe pas / doesn't exist : '"+location.port+"'"); //****
}
```

I Thought that my LAMP works listening port 80, but, when I call my test page (first step):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>SW map</title>
  <body>
    <h1>Pour voir</h1>
    <section></section>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the console show these messages:

```
===================
app.js :

app.js:1:9
serviceWorker n'existe pas / doesn't exist : ''
```

So, my test run, but **the location port isn't 80 and no serviceWorker exists**...

Could you please show me my mistake(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, down on bottom of mdn page :

> When testing you can get around the HTTPS restriction by checking the
>   "Enable Service Workers over HTTP (when toolbox is open)" option in
>   the Firefox Developer Tools settings.

It does function.